# Dark matter Thermal average cross section expansion

Tags: statistical-mechanics, dark-matter

In many papers and books, including paper written by P.Gondolo & G.Gelmini in 1991, COSMIC ABUNDANCES OF STABLE PARTICLES: IMPROVED ANALYSIS, it is well known that for non relativistic gas, you can write down annihilation cross section times relative velocity $\sigma v$ by expanding this in powers of $v^2$ when you can write $s = 4m^2+m^2v^2$. Then, you thermal average this,

$$\begin{equation} \tag{1}
<\sigma v> = <a + bv^2 + \dots>
\\= a+  \frac{3}{2}b\bigg(\frac{T}{m}\bigg) + \dots
\end{equation}$$
*$k_B=1$ unit.

Question is :

1. What does it mean exactly by saying "Thermal average"  this? Does it mean use the relation

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}m<v^2> = \frac{3}{2}T
\end{align}$$
The equipartition relation? But if i follow this relation, <$bv^2> \neq \frac{3}{2}b\bigg(\frac{T}{m}\bigg)$.  So where does this factor $3/2$ came from? I want to know how the equation (1) above is related, bracketed one and un-bracketed one. If the equation(1) to be hold, then we should get

2. Why thermally averaged center of mass energy $<s>=4m^2 + 6mT?$ Is the relation $<m^2v^2> = 6mT$ from considering reduced mass of $\mu = \frac{m*m}{m+m} = 1/2$, $\frac{3}{2}T = \frac{1}{2}<\mu v^2>$ so that $<m^2v^2> = 6mT?$. This also cannot explain the equation (1).

I am adding a paragraph from the paper that explains about this :

> For non-relativistic gases, the thermally averaged annihilation cross section $<\sigma v>$ has sometimes been approximated with the value of $\sigma v$ at $s = <s>$, the thermally averaged center-of-mass squared energy, and the expansion $s = 4m2 + 6mT$ has been taken. Such an approximation is good only when $\sigma v$ is almost linear in s, i.e. unfortunately almost never. A better approximation for non-relativistic gases is to expand $<\sigma v>$ in powers of $x^{-1} = T/m$. A common way of doing this (cf. e.g. ref. [1]) is to write $s = 4m^2 + m^2v^2$ expand $\sigma v$ in powers of $v^2$ and take the thermal average to obtain $$\begin{align}
> <\sigma v> = <a + bv^2 + \dots>
> \\= a+  \frac{3}{2}b\bigg(\frac{T}{m}\bigg) + \dots
> \end{align}$$